# Custom add_rewrite_rule & permalinks

Tags: permalinks

I need to convert this url :
`http://localhost/wordpress/mp3s/mp3/name?playlist=123`

To This:
`http://localhost/wordpress/mp3s/mp3/name/playlist/123`

Is it possible ?

Here is my try :

```
add_rewrite_rule( '^mp3s/mp3/([^/]+)/playlist/([^/]+)/?$',
    'index.php?songs=$matches[1]&playlist=$matches[2]',
'top' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code to `functions.php` file:

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^mp3s/mp3/([^/]+)/playlist/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?page_id={PAGE_ID}&songs=$matches[1]&playlist=$matches[2]', 'top');
}

add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');

function custom_rewrite_tag() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%songs%', '([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_tag('%playlist%', '([^&]+)');
}

add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

Create a file named my-custom-template.php in your themes root directory as following:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Music
 */
get_header(); 

global $wp_query;
echo 'Songs : ' . $wp_query->query_vars['songs'];
echo '<br />';
echo 'Play List : ' . $wp_query->query_vars['playlist'];
// ... more ...
get_footer(); 
?>
```

Using this template, create a page and replace `{PAGE_ID}` with built page ID in the first code.

Then, go to **Setting -> Permalinks** and click on `Save Changes`.

Comment: What is the Best way to get 123 value ?

Comment: Code updated. Please accept your answer so the question is no longer considered unanswered; click the check mark under the vote arrows on the left.